# Dynamic html form using jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I want to fill the value part of a html form in jsp with declared String in jsp. I am using jsp EL like that:

```
<% 
  ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select id from mytable");   
  String id=rs.getString(1); 
%>
<form action="process.jsp" method="post">   
  ID: <input type="text" name="myId" value="${id}"> 
</form>
```

But it's giving an error saying:

> invalid input tag location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this without EL like this..

```
<% 
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select id from mytable");   
String id=rs.getString(1); 
%> 
<form action="process.jsp" method="post">   
ID: <input type="text" name="myId" value="<%=id%>"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you should put below your:

```
String id=rs.getString(1);
```

this code:

```
pageContext.setAttribute("id", id);
```

Comment: No you don't need to put it, you can use it directly with `${id}`.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to put the `input` tag inside a `fieldset` or a `div` block because in strict `HTML` form inputs must be wrapped in a `fieldset`.

> In the **[fieldset - HTML | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)** documentation it says that:
>
> The HTML  element is used to group several controls as well
>   as labels () within a web form.

And make sure you close the `input` tag, your code should be like this:

```
<form action="process.jsp" method="post"> 
   <fieldset>  
        ID: <input type="text" name="myId" value="${id}" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```